# Possible Node.js memory leak when using callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

I've been coding with Node.js, but since I'm not that familiar with how GC works with async methods, I believe I created a memory leak in this code:

```
function getPriceCC(coins, chn) {

        // Get the spot price of the pair and send it to general
        cc.priceFull(coins.map(function(c){return c.toUpperCase();}),['USD', 'EUR']).
        then(prices => {
                var msg = '__**CryptoCompare**__\n';

                for(var i = 0; i < coins.length; i++)
                        msg += ('- **' + coins[i].toUpperCase() + '-USD** is : `' +
                            prices[coins[i].toUpperCase()]['USD']['PRICE'] + ' USD` (`' +
                            Math.round(prices[coins[i].toUpperCase()]['USD']['CHANGEPCT24HOUR']*100)/100 + '%`).\n'
                            );


                chn.send(msg);

                delete chn;
                delete coins;
                delete msg;
                delete prices;

                })
        .catch(console.error);

}
```

I read about closure, so I tried deleting the variables inside the callback function, but it keeps stacking up. I've also found that some people dislike the use of `var` and say my code is horrible, while some example code from Google uses `var`.

If any clarification is needed or extra code required, please do tell.

Note: Node version is 8.0.0, and the instance is Ubuntu 16.04 on AWS.

Comment: Your `delete` operations don't do anything. `delete` is just for deleting properties of an object. `var` vs `let` will make no difference given your code. When you say it stacks up, I assume you mean memory continues to build and never gets freed. Is that right?

Comment: @spanky Thank you. Yes, memory isn't freed.

Comment: How are you measuring your memory usage? To detect an actual leak, you have to do heap snapshots to see what is actually allocated in the heap and to see what continues to grow (even after you've given GC a chance to run).  I don't see anything obvious in this code that would cause a leak.  90+% of the time people think they have a leak, all they are looking at is peak memory usage, not an actual leak so that's the first thing to figure out.  Of course, `chn.send()` or `cc.priceFull()` could actually have leaks, but we can't see that code.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would leak memory. Only thing might be if the reference to the callback passed to `then` never gets relinquished internally. You can try "nulling" those variables, but in general, you don't need to help the GC; you just need to make sure you're not permanently holding references.

Comment: @jfriend00 this is code from a bot that runs 24/7, so after 2 or 3 days, the RAM allocated from the process is huge. I'm on a headless terminal. Do you know how to take a snapshot of an already-running process?

Comment: @spanky I'll try nulling and I'll get back. Thanks.

Comment: I think you will have to instrument your code to output heap snapshots every so often and then you can analyze them after it has run awhile.  You don't need to `null` local variables or function arguments as long as your scope doesn't last forever.  The GC will take care of that just fine.  I suspect the memory usage issue in your server is elsewhere.

Comment: @O.VonSeckendorff: To be clear, the only thing nulling may do is give you an indication that there may be a problem elsewhere WRT your callback. It's not an actual solution to the memory leak.

Comment: @spanky - Why do you think a callback passed to a `.then()` handler would not get released?  That would be a horrible bug in the promise implementation that would affect tons of code.  And, the parent promise reference is not even retained anywhere here.

Comment: @jfriend00: Do you know that the `.then()` being called is from the standard Promise library? Or that the parent Promise object isn't retained elsewhere? Seems like there's plenty of potential for user-created leaks.

Comment: @spanky - No, but it would be a completely dysfunctional promise implementation that accumulates `.then()` handler references and never releases them.  That code would be untenable in any server environment.  Yes, it could be that broken, but it seems way, way more likely that the problem is elsewhere in the server or is in the `cc.priceFull()` or `chn.send()` methods.

Comment: FYI, a work-around until you solve the memory accumulation is to run your app clustered with two nodes and during a period of low usage (often once per day), restart one, then when it's back up, restart the other.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm considering doing that, like having a main node and a restarter node, but it feels dirty.

Comment: Well, you should figure out what is causing the memory accumulation and fix it.  My suggestion was a work-around until them.  But, LOTS of very well known server processes restart themselves every once in awhile to clean up any accidental resource accumulation.  It's not a bad practice in a production environment if it's done in a way that does not cause service interruption.  Having such a procedure can also allow you to upgrade the code without service interruption too.

Comment: Thanks to both. I'm using pm2 for now to manage the crash and take snapshots. I hope I get to clear this up.